# Android Java AsyncTask executes twice after activity restarts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using some AsyncTasks in background for purposes in my Native Android Java application, however when i click the button "Apply changes and Restart Activity", once the activity is restarted AsyncTasks execute twice. this is really strange. because i have some monitoring purposes with AsyncTasks, so i used `new MyAsyncTask.Execute()` for execute the class in a Handler up every 1 minute. if application run normally, it's very cool. but when i used to restart by the mentioned Button in Android studio, i am facing the issue. with this issue, i am in a trouble that some logs are duplicating.

Comment: could you please show codes a bit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is originally from android architecture. when Activity gets destroy, automatically the activity restarts several times in same thread. in case of that single execution may run several times. the following code helps to solve this issue.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        pusher.disconnect();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is relative to the **place of your asynctask execution**. By click button , in oncreateview or in oncreate of your activity. You can **have debug** in start of your asynctask(preexecute or doinbackground) and for every time execution **check the variables of your activity(if your asynctask is inside of your activity)**.The best way for recognizing of time proper of your operations , is checking of some parameters of your activity inside of your asynctask **and selecting of proper time for operation doing**.Do not forget the *place of your asynctask also is important but you must have your controls inside of the asynctask*.

Answer (score 0):

If you share your code it may be easy to understand, but it seems you only have a problem with the application's life cycle, see the documentation:
[Understand the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)